# Add new language to iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, localization

I would like to translate an iOS app which is only available in Chinese on Chinese store. I'm not the owner of the app. I have succeeded in installing it by switching to Chinese store.
My intend is to just add the new language localization files by translating original Chinese files.

- It seems that I can't just add new files (even resources) to existing IPA without breaking the signature
- I have my own official Apple developer certificate, can I add the new files and resign the IPA with it ?
- I have also tried to decrypt the IPA using clutch to resign it with my own certificate, but installing it on my device fails.

I want to use the application on iOS 9. I have used clutch on an old iPhone 4 with iOS 7 to be able to jailbreak it easily.

Answer (score 2):

**No you can't do this**. According to Apple no one can reverse engineer the app code. It's highly secured. So you can't do whatever you are trying to do with the IPA .

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.
First step is to decrypt the binary with Clutch.
Second step is to add expected resources.
And finally, the application has to be resigned.

For those who would be interested, you can find my work on https://github.com/niclet/yi-home-ios